# Reusing variables in PGSQL queries

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I have a query, which I have simplified a little to:

```
WITH users AS (
    SELECT member_id FROM group_members AS gm 
        JOIN groups AS g on gm.group_id = g.id 
        WHERE g.id = 1337 OR g.parents @> ARRAY[1337]
    )
UPDATE access SET revoked = TRUE 
    WHERE user_id IN (SELECT member_id FROM users)

RETURNING user_id;
```

This works, but I have to put in that id value (1337) several times. This isn't so bad in my abstract example, but gets really ugly with my more complex real world query & since I'm using PHP/PDO I have to pass in the same variable multiple times.

What I'm looking for is some trick to declare my variable once and then reuse it, like:

```
DECLARE gid = 1337
WITH users AS (
    SELECT member_id FROM group_members AS gm 
        JOIN groups AS g on gm.group_id = g.id 
        WHERE g.id = gid OR g.parents @> ARRAY[gid]
    )
UPDATE access SET revoked = TRUE 
    WHERE user_id IN (SELECT member_id FROM users)

RETURNING user_id;
```

But obviously that doesnt work.

Is there a way to declare a variable once in a pgsql query and reuse it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with gid as (
    select 1337 as gid
), users as (
    select member_id
    from
        group_members as gm 
        join
        groups as g on gm.group_id = g.id 
    where
        g.id = (select gid from gid) or
        g.parents @> array[(select gid from gid)]
)
update access
set revoked = true 
where user_id in (select member_id from users)
```

or do a cross join if the subquery is too ugly

```
with gid as (
    select 1337 as gid
), users as (
    select member_id
    from
        group_members as gm 
        join
        groups as g on gm.group_id = g.id
        cross join
        gid
    where g.id = gid or g.parents @> array[gid]
)
update access
set revoked = true 
where user_id in (select member_id from users)
```

But if you are passing parameters from PHP then I don't see the problem of just placing the parameters holders in the place of `1337`

Comment: In PDO, you can only use the parameters once, so i have to pass 1337 in multiple times. I didnt try cross join, that may be a decent method

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is not a *good* way. Clodaldo has shown the only way that's really viable in plain SQL.

The other way, and what I generally do, is wrap it in a trivial SQL function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_whatever(gid integer) RETURNS SETOF integer AS $$
WITH users AS (
    SELECT member_id FROM group_members AS gm 
        JOIN groups AS g on gm.group_id = g.id 
        WHERE g.id = $1 OR g.parents @> ARRAY[$1]
    )
UPDATE access SET revoked = TRUE 
    WHERE user_id IN (SELECT member_id FROM users)
RETURNING user_id;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

SELECT * FROM do_whatever(1337);
```

Unfortunately PostgreSQL doesn't have `TEMPORARY` functions, and `DO` blocks cannot take parameters or return a rowset. So it's not ideal, but it works.